# Exclude contents of directory with maven rpm plugin

Tags: maven, mapping, pom.xml, rpm

I am creating a pom file with multiple mappings.  I am trying to combine different functions into one neat package of mappings and I am having some trouble getting it to read some of the functions as well as pass permissions properly.

The directory structure is as follows:

```
/conf
  /folder1
  /folder2
  /folder3
/bin
```

I can get bin to map properly using the following setup:

```
<mapping>
   <directory>/opt/bin</directory>
   <filemode>755</filemode>
   <username>myUser</username>
   <groupname>myUser</groupname>
   <sources>
 <source>
   <location>bin</location>
 </source>
   <sources>
</mapping>
```

What I want to accomplish is to put all of conf into /opt/conf exactly the same structure with the same permissions.  However I have an assembly plugin that takes contents from folder2 and zips them up.  I want to skip the contents of folder2 in the mapping, and then include the zip file in the folder when it unwraps.  So I will have /opt/folder2/contents.zip

Here are my attempted mappings for that, but they are not reading properly:

```
<mapping>
<directory>/opt/conf</directory>
<filemode>755</filemode>
<username>myUser</username>
<groupname>myUser</groupname>
<sources>
    <source>
        <location>conf</location>
        <excludes>
            <exclude>folder2</exclude>
        </excludes>
    </source>
</sources>
 </mapping>
 <mapping>
<directory>/opt/conf/folder2</directory>
<filemode>755</filemode>
<username>myUser</username>
<groupname>myUser</groupname>
<sources>
    <source>
        <location>target</location>
        <includes>
           <include>*.zip</include>
        </includes>
    </source>
</sources>
</mapping>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I can see your pom file should works, but maybe you run it not from the project build directory or needed files located in another folder, which means that you need to specify a relative path to those files in <location> tag.